# Django App build failing with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2017

I am currently getting this error when Using the Python->Publish feature in Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise).

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "C:\"path to static files"/static
 Illegal characters in path.    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Python Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets   105
```

It is coming from this line in Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets `<FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(_DjangoStaticFiles)" Condition="'%(FullPath)' != ''">`

It seems like the target files are having trouble gathering the static files.

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was reluctant to change Python Tools files, but this change worked.

From:

```
<FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="@(_DjangoStaticFiles)" Condition="'%(FullPath)' != ''">
```

To:

```
<DestinationRelativePath>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`))</DestinationRelativePath>
```